# buzzwire game in arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm tring to make buzzwire game in arduino and this is what I have from now on.

```
#include <TM1637.h> // include display library
#include <pitches.h> // include pitches

TM1637 *_display = new TM1637(12, 13); // create display object, 12 = CLK (clock), 13 = D10 (data)

// music
int songState = 0;

int melody[] = {
 NOTE_F4, NOTE_E4, NOTE_D4, NOTE_CS4,
 NOTE_C4, NOTE_B3, NOTE_AS3, NOTE_A3,
 NOTE_G3, NOTE_A3, NOTE_AS3, NOTE_A3, 
 NOTE_G3, NOTE_C4, 0, 

 NOTE_C4, NOTE_A3, NOTE_A3, NOTE_A3,
 NOTE_GS3, NOTE_A3, NOTE_F4, NOTE_C4, 
 NOTE_C4, NOTE_A3, NOTE_AS3, NOTE_AS3, 
 NOTE_AS3, NOTE_C4, NOTE_D4, 0, 

 NOTE_AS3, NOTE_G3, NOTE_G3, NOTE_G3,
 NOTE_FS3, NOTE_G3, NOTE_E4, NOTE_D4, 
 NOTE_D4, NOTE_AS3, NOTE_A3, NOTE_A3, 
 NOTE_A3, NOTE_AS3, NOTE_C4, 0,

 NOTE_C4, NOTE_A3, NOTE_A3, NOTE_A3,
 NOTE_GS3, NOTE_A3, NOTE_A4, NOTE_F4, 
 NOTE_F4, NOTE_C4, NOTE_B3, NOTE_G4, 
 NOTE_G4, NOTE_G4, NOTE_G4, 0,

 NOTE_G4, NOTE_E4, NOTE_G4, NOTE_G4,
 NOTE_FS4, NOTE_G4, NOTE_D4, NOTE_G4, 
 NOTE_G4, NOTE_FS4, NOTE_G4, NOTE_C4, 
 NOTE_B3, NOTE_C4, NOTE_B3, NOTE_C4, 0
};

int tempo[] = {
 8, 16, 8, 16,
 8, 16, 8, 16,
 16, 16, 16, 8,
 16, 8, 3,

 12, 16, 16, 16,
 8, 16, 8, 16,
 8, 16, 8, 16,
 8, 16, 4, 12,

 12, 16, 16, 16,
 8, 16, 8, 16,
 8, 16, 8, 16,
 8, 16, 4, 12,

 12, 16, 16, 16,
 8, 16, 8, 16,
 8, 16, 8, 16,
 8, 16, 4, 16,

 12, 17, 17, 17,
 8, 12, 17, 17, 
 17, 8, 16, 8,
 16, 8, 16, 8, 1 
};

// non blocking setup
// free play
unsigned long previousMillis1 = 0; // time words last changed
const long interval1 = 1500; // interval between changing

// music
unsigned long previousMillis2 = 0; // time last changed
const long interval2 = 100; // interval between notes

int displayStatus = 0; // keep track of what's displayed
int mode = 0; // keep track of game mode -- change to 0 or 1 for different modes

bool countdown = false;

unsigned long previousMillis3 = 0; // time last changed
const long interval3 = 1000; // interval between countdown
int count = 20; // challenge mode timer

void setup() { 
 // put your setup code here, to run once:
 pinMode(9, INPUT); // setup circuit
 pinMode(10, OUTPUT); // setup buzzer 1
 pinMode(11, OUTPUT); // setup buzzer 2
 pinMode(2, INPUT); // setup button

 _display->set(5); // set brightness
 _display->point(false); // remove colon
 _display->init(); // start display
}

void loop(void) {
 // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
 int conductVal = analogRead(9);

 Serial.print("Conduction sensor reads");
 Serial.println(conductVal);

 if(conductVal>410){
  //digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
  tone(11,550,400);
  tone(10,0,400);
  delay(5000);
  countdown=false;
 }
 if(mode == 0) {
   // free play
 toggleFreePlay(); 

 }
 else {
 // challenge mode
 if(digitalRead(2) == HIGH) {
 delay(25);
 if(digitalRead(2) == HIGH) {
 countdown = true; // stop the countdown
 }
 else {
 countdown = false; // stop the countdown
 }
 }
 if(countdown) {
 showCountdown(); // advance countdown
 }
 }
 if(digitalRead(10) == HIGH) {
 delay(25);
 if(digitalRead(10) == HIGH) {
 while(digitalRead(10) == HIGH) {
 buzz(11, NOTE_B0, 1000/24);
 }
 }
 }
 else
 sing();
}

void showCountdown() {
 // countdown the time remaining
 unsigned long currentMillis = millis(); // current time
 if (currentMillis - previousMillis3 >= interval3) {
 previousMillis3 = currentMillis;
 --count;
 showNumber(count);
 if(count == 0) {
 // game over
 countdown = false;
 count = 20;
 // reset countdown
 // buzz 3 times
 buzz(11, NOTE_B0, 1000/24); 
 delay(100);
 buzz(11, NOTE_B0, 1000/24);
 delay(100);
 buzz(11, NOTE_B0, 1000/24);
 }
 }
}


void showNumber(int number) {
 // show numbers (maximum 99) on display
 _display->display(0, 25); // write - to segment 1
 _display->display(3, 25); // write - to segment 4

 // write number to middle of display

  if(number == 10)
  {
     _display->display(1,1);
   _display->display(2,0);
  }
  else if(number > 9)
  {
   _display->display(1,1);
   int newVal = number - 10;
   _display->display(2, newVal);
  }
  else
  {
     _display->display(1,0);
   _display->display(2,number);
  }
}

void toggleFreePlay() {
 // scroll between words without blocking
 unsigned long currentMillis = millis(); // current time
 if (currentMillis - previousMillis1 >= interval1) {
 previousMillis1 = currentMillis;
 if(displayStatus == 1) 
 showPlay();
 else
 showFree();
 }
}

void showPlay() {
 // write "PLAY" to the display
 _display->display(0, 21); // write P to segment 1
 _display->display(1, 18); // write L to segment 2
 _display->display(2, 10); // write A to segment 3
 _display->display(3, 4); // write Y to segment 4
 displayStatus = 2;
}

void showFree() {
 // write "Free" to the display
 _display->display(0, 15); // write F to segment 1
 _display->display(1, 23); // write r to segment 2
 _display->display(2, 14); // write E to segment 3
 _display->display(3, 14); // write E to segment 4
 displayStatus = 1;
}

void buzz(int targetPin, long frequency, long length) {
 /* Buzzer example function by Rob Faludi
 http://www.faludi.com
 https://gist.github.com/AnthonyDiGirolamo/1405180 
 */
 long delayValue = 1000000/frequency/2; // calculate the delay value between transitions
 //// 1 second's worth of microseconds, divided by the frequency, then split in half since
 //// there are two phases to each cycle
 long numCycles = frequency * length/ 1000; // calculate the number of cycles for proper timing
 //// multiply frequency, which is really cycles per second, by the number of seconds to
 //// get the total number of cycles to produce
 for (long i=0; i < numCycles; i++){ // for the calculated length of time...
 digitalWrite(targetPin,HIGH); // write the buzzer pin high to push out the diaphragm
 delayMicroseconds(delayValue); // wait for the calculated delay value
 digitalWrite(targetPin,LOW); // write the buzzer pin low to pull back the diaphragm
 delayMicroseconds(delayValue); // wait again for the calculated delay value
 }
}

void sing() {
 // play the song in a non blocking way
 unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

 if (currentMillis - previousMillis2 >= interval2) {
 previousMillis2 = currentMillis;
 int noteDuration = 1000 / tempo[songState];
 buzz(10, melody[songState], noteDuration);
 int pauseBetweenNotes = noteDuration;
 delay(pauseBetweenNotes);

 // stop the tone playing:
 buzz(10, 0, noteDuration);

 ++songState;
 // start song again if finished
 if(songState > 79) {
 songState = 14; // skip intro 
 } 
 }
}
```

First I want to stop continuous buzzing during the game, and I want to make buzzer react when the handle touches the course. Plus, I also want to know how can I change the mode in arduino( and breadboard).

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: First align your code (make the { and } nicely arranged, to easier read your sketch.

Comment: `change the mode` ... what is `mode`?